# Should referenced std::shared_ptr be deleted after method goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, singly-linked-list

I am learning smart pointers and what is better to learn it than to implement a simple structure, such as Linked List, on the heap.

I created a linked list structure as follows...

```
// linked list node definition
#ifndef __LINKED_LIST_NODE_H
#define __LINKED_LIST_NODE_H

class LinkedListNode {
    friend class LinkedList;
public:
    int                 m_value;
    LinkedListNode *    m_pNext;
public:
    LinkedListNode();
    LinkedListNode(int);
    LinkedListNode(const LinkedListNode &);
    ~LinkedListNode();
};

#endif

// linked list definition
#ifndef __LINKED_LIST_H
#define __LINKED_LIST_H

class LinkedList {
    LinkedListNode * m_pHead;
    LinkedListNode * m_pTail;
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(int);
    LinkedList(const LinkedList &);
    ~LinkedList();
    void PrintList() const;
    void AddItem(int);
    void RemoveItem(int);
    LinkedListNode * FindNode(int) const;
    LinkedListNode * FindMin() const;
    LinkedListNode * FindMax() const;
};

#endif
```

Here are necessarry methods (constructors and destructors) for both LinkedListNode and LinkedList classes to see, what it looks like (IIRC these should be correct)...

```
// list node
LinkedListNode::LinkedListNode()
{
    m_value = 0;
    m_pNext = nullptr;
}

LinkedListNode::LinkedListNode(int value)
{
    m_value = value;
    m_pNext = nullptr;
}

LinkedListNode::LinkedListNode(const LinkedListNode & copyNode)
{
    m_value = copyNode.m_value;
    m_pNext = copyNode.m_pNext;
}

LinkedListNode::~LinkedListNode()
{
    // not needed, no dynamic allocation
}


// linked list
LinkedList::LinkedList()
{
    m_pHead = nullptr;
    m_pTail = m_pHead;
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(int value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>newNode{ new LinkedListNode(value) };
    m_pHead = newNode.get();
    m_pHead->m_pNext = nullptr;
    m_pTail = m_pHead;
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList & copyList)
{
    if (copyList.m_pHead == nullptr)
    {
        m_pHead = nullptr;
        m_pTail = m_pHead;
    }
    else
    {
        std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>NodeResource{ new LinkedListNode(*copyList.m_pHead) };

        LinkedListNode * tempNode = NodeResource.get();

        m_pHead = tempNode;

        while (tempNode->m_pNext != nullptr)
        {           
            std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>NodeResourceNext{ new LinkedListNode(*tempNode->m_pNext) };
            tempNode->m_pNext = NodeResourceNext.get();
            tempNode = NodeResourceNext.get();
        }

        m_pTail = tempNode;
    }
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    // not needed, allocating using smart pointers
}
```

Now, the LinkedList class contains AddItem method, whose body is this:

```
void LinkedList::AddItem(int value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>newNode{ new LinkedListNode(value) };

    if (m_pHead == nullptr) // linked list is empty
    {
        m_pHead = newNode.get();
        m_pTail = newNode.get();
    }
    else
    {
        m_pTail->m_pNext = newNode.get();
        m_pTail = newNode.get();
    }
}
```

And I don't know why, but when I try to add an item to my linked list, it seems the newNode variable is removed when you get out of scope of the method.

Here is what it looks like when I try to debug the program...

**First we start off with en empty linked list**
[image: Empty Linked List]

Then inside the AddItem function I get the following results (it looks like the m_pHead and m_pTail corretly point to the newly created newNode on heap.

[image: Inside Method AddItem()]

but when the AddItem() method goes out of scope, this is what I am left with

[image: After AddItem() method]

I thought, std::share_ptr is deleted once nothing references the pointer. In my case newNode is referenced by two pointers, m_pHead and m_pTail. Is it really deleted upon leaving the AddItem() method, or is there a flaw in my code I haven't spotted?

Thank you very much for your input, guys.

Comment: a shared ptr is deallocated when the last shared ptr referencing it is deleted. It has no idea that you are also using regular pointers to point to it.

Comment: You might think that those screenshots help but they actually hurt: it clearly shows you've put some effort in your question but it makes it very difficult for us to answer because we can't copy anything and have to retype everything.

Comment: @ereOn Sorry for the inconvenience, I am not very experienced user of this site.

Comment: @Andy: No worries. The good thing with SO is that you can always update/fix your questions/answers for the benefit of all :)

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning `newNode.get()` to a raw pointer (`LinkedListNode*`) member of your `LinkedListNode`.

This is incorrect because a `shared_ptr` (in this case at least) owns the underlying pointer. When it goes out of scope, the associated memory is freed yet your `LinkedListNode` still has a member to the formerly-allocated memory.

You probably should change the definition of `LinkedListNode` so that its `LinkedListNode*` members are `shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>` instead, ensuring the underlying memory gets referenced as long as your instances live.

Comment: Oh I see, so using the .get() method od std::shared_ptr actually doesn't add reference to the variable? Meaning the compiler has no idea something is actually pointing to the variable and thus deleting it when it goes out of scope? Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: no need for a `shared_ptr`, he could just make `m_pHead` and `m_pNext` `unique_ptr`s and he'd be fine

Comment: @RedAlert: Likely but we don't have enough context to tell if `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` should be used (for all we know some other piece of the code might need `shared_ptr` of the nodes). That being said, the choice of the smart pointer to use is probably not the first problem to solve with this question.

Comment: Btw, smart pointers in a list implementation are scary - if a list is large you get extremely deep call stack, since cleanup is done in destructor, recursively..

Comment: @ereOn I was told pointers must not own resources. E.g. Object * newObject = new Object(); is a bad practice. I was told, using smart pointers to manage memory on the heap is a much better way. Is that wrong?

Comment: @Andy: Anybody who speaks only in generalities is probably talking nonsense. Smart pointers themselves have to be implemented using such constructs so I wouldn't say it is a bad practice. That being said, smart pointers are very common and should be the default choice when dealing with dynamically allocated structures. They force the person allocating memory to think about its deallocation. Depending on your design, you might opt for `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, whichever makes most sense. I rarely have to deal with naked pointers, and mostly when dealing with a C interface.

Comment: @Andy The issue is that you aren't using smart pointers to manage memory. Your linked list doesn't have any smart pointer members which own anything.

Comment: @ereOn I rewrote my LinkedList class to include `std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode> m_pHead;` and `std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode> m_pTail;`, altered the AddItem() function and it works now. You said you thought`std::unique_ptr` might be a better idea in this case. I am really, really new to smart pointers and I thought unique pointers were only used inside a function, as a temporary solution. Are there any advantages to using `std::unique_ptr` over `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @Andy Pros: Lower memory footprint and close-to-none performance penalty compared to raw pointers but its very likely not a concern (since you are still at the design phase, you shouldn't be worried about such micro-optimizations anyway). The real reason to pick one or the other is the semantic of it: do you want to share ownership of the pointer or not ? If not (usually you don't), go for `unique_ptr`. Beware because you won't be able to copy it but only move it and this "restriction" will propagate to the embedding class, `LinkedListNode` as well (this might be a good thing in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far too long, but I see that you seem not to use `std::shared_ptr` in an appropriate way. For example,

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(int value)
{
    std::shared_ptr<LinkedListNode>newNode{ new LinkedListNode(value) };
    m_pHead = newNode.get();
    m_pHead->m_pNext = nullptr;
    m_pTail = m_pHead;
}   // <-- call of std::shared_ptr::~std::shared_ptr
```

The `newNode` will be destroyed at the end of the function body. This will then also delete the object the pointer to which is shared (between exactly one `std::shared_ptr`), whereby leaving `m_pHead` with a **dangling pointer**.

The basic idea of `shared_ptr` is to *share* ownership of some resources in such a way that as long as any of the sharing owners is still alive, then so is the resource: the resource is deleted when the last owner dies.

In the vast majority of good code, resources are owned by certain objects, i.e. shared ownership is a rather rare and niche situation. There is definitely no need for it in a simple linked list implementation.

---

One possible ownership model for the linked list is that each node owns the next node. Then you would have

```
template<typename T> class list;
template<typename T>
class node {
  friend class list<T>;
  T m_data;
  unique_ptr<node> m_next;
  explicit node(T const&value)
  : m_data(value) {}
  node(T const&value, unique_ptr<node>&&n)
  : m_data(value), m_next(n) {}
public:
  node*next() { return m_next.get(); }
  const node*next() const { return m_next.get(); }
};

template<typename T>
class list {
  typedef node<T> node_type;
  unique_ptr<node_type> m_head;
  node_type            *m_tail;
  ~list() {}  // destructor of m_head destroys all nodes recursively
  explicit list(T const&value)
  : m_head(new node_type(value)), m_tail(m_head.get()) {}
  void push(T const&value)
  {
    // move the existing m_head to be m_next of the new node,
    // which in turn becomes the new m_head. m_tail is unaffected.
    m_head = new node_type(value,std::move(m_head));
  }
};
```

However, you must be careful how you implement insertion and slicing etc.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` asside, do you think, using `std::unique_ptr` might be a better (or the only viable) idea in this case?

Comment: @Andy Before you decide what kind of smart pointer you want to use, you need to first have a coherent ownership model. Who do you think should own a `LinkedListNode`?

Comment: Yes, use `unique_ptr` for `LinkedListNode::m_pNext` and `LinkedList::m_pHead`, but not `m_pTail` (as this is merely an observer). This will ensure that by all the nodes are automatically deleted by the destructor of `LinkedList` (in fact you need not to implement that destructor).

Comment: @RedAlert The owned of a node should definitely be the `LinkedList` the `LinkedListNode` is in. Is therefore `std::unique_ptr` the better way to go?

Comment: @Walter I tried changing `LinkedListNode * m_pNext` inside the LinkedListNode class to smart pointer and I was then unable to access the m_pNext variable. Would you know why was that? I haven't really found any detailed documentation on this topic.

Comment: Have a look around [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), for example.

Comment: @Walter Thank you for the URL, Walter. I guess I will dive deeper into it to try and understand how smart pointers really work.

Comment: @Walter I just checked your last implementation using templates and I must admit I am nowhere as far in programming to deeply understand what all your code means. For example, seeing the address of a reference (in the parameter of node constructor) `&&n` is something entirely new to me.

Comment: `unique_ptr` uses **move** semantics instead of copy (if you copied it, it would no longer be unique). Move semantics and `std::unique_ptr` have both been added to C++ in 2011 and require a new type of reference: an rvalue reference which uses the `&&`. The link in my previous comment provides excellent explanation of almost all of C++, including the language itself.